# Adding a library to a Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, papaparse

I am trying to use papaparse.js with a Suitelet so that I can upload a file to Netsuite's file cabinet using the suitelet and then parse the file using the Papa.parse() function in the papaparse api.  However I get an error that Papa is undefined.

I have tried a few different methods.

- Attach the papaparse.js file as a library file on the suitelet script record
- Create a client script record for the papaparse.js and call the client script using form.setScript()

I have never used a library file with a suitelet and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code where I have the papaparse.js file attached to the suitelet record as library file.

```js
function suitelet(request, response){
 var fileId = request.getParameter('fileId')
 if(request.getMethod() == 'GET'){
  var form = nlapiCreateForm('Add File', true
   form.addField('custpage_file','file', 'Select File')
   form.addSubmitButton('Save');
   response.writePage(form)
  
    }else{
   var form = nlapiCreateForm('Add File', true)
   var file = request.getFile('custpage_file')
   file.setFolder(895)
      var uploadedFile = nlapiSubmitFile(file)
      var fileValue = file.getValue
   var papaData =  Papa.parse(fileValue)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues implementing Papa Parse in Suitescript, but I had success using Baby Parse. You can make it work by including the code in a function, or you can try adding it as a library. Here's an example:

```
function suitelet(request, response){
    var fileId = request.getParameter('fileId')
    if(request.getMethod() == 'GET'){
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('Add File', true
            form.addField('custpage_file','file', 'Select File')
            form.addSubmitButton('Save');
            response.writePage(form)

    }else{
      var form = nlapiCreateForm('Add File', true)
      var file = request.getFile('custpage_file')
         file.setFolder(895)
      var uploadedFile = nlapiSubmitFile(file)
      var fileValue = file.getValue
      var papaData =  CSVParser().parse(fileValue);
   }
}


/*
    Baby Parse
    v0.4.1
    https://github.com/Rich-Harris/BabyParse
*/
function CSVParser(){function e(r,n){if(Array.isArray(r)){var i=[];return r.forEach(function(t){"object"==typeof t?i.push(e(t.file,t.config)):i.push(e(t,n))}),i}var i={data:[],errors:[]};if(!/(\.csv|\.txt)$/.test(r))return i.errors.push({type:"",code:"",message:"Unsupported file type.",row:""}),i;try{var a=fs.readFileSync(r).toString();return t(a,n)}catch(s){return i.errors.push(s),i}}function t(e,t){var r=a(t),i=new n(r),s=i.parse(e);return f(r.complete)&&r.complete(s),s}function r(e,t){function r(){"object"==typeof t&&("string"==typeof t.delimiter&&1==t.delimiter.length&&-1==l.BAD_DELIMITERS.indexOf(t.delimiter)&&(o=t.delimiter),("boolean"==typeof t.quotes||t.quotes instanceof Array)&&(f=t.quotes),"string"==typeof t.newline&&(d=t.newline))}function n(e){if("object"!=typeof e)return[];var t=[];for(var r in e)t.push(r);return t}function i(e,t){var r="";"string"==typeof e&&(e=JSON.parse(e)),"string"==typeof t&&(t=JSON.parse(t));var n=e instanceof Array&&e.length>0,i=!(t[0]instanceof Array);if(n){for(var s=0;s<e.length;s++)s>0&&(r+=o),r+=a(e[s],s);t.length>0&&(r+=d)}for(var f=0;f<t.length;f++){for(var l=n?e.length:t[f].length,u=0;l>u;u++){u>0&&(r+=o);var p=n&&i?e[u]:u;r+=a(t[f][p],u)}f<t.length-1&&(r+=d)}return r}function a(e,t){if("undefined"==typeof e||null===e)return"";e=e.toString().replace(/"/g,'""');var r="boolean"==typeof f&&f||f instanceof Array&&f[t]||s(e,l.BAD_DELIMITERS)||e.indexOf(o)>-1||" "==e.charAt(0)||" "==e.charAt(e.length-1);return r?'"'+e+'"':e}function s(e,t){for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++)if(e.indexOf(t[r])>-1)return!0;return!1}var f=!1,o=",",d="\r\n";if(r(),"string"==typeof e&&(e=JSON.parse(e)),e instanceof Array){if(!e.length||e[0]instanceof Array)return i(null,e);if("object"==typeof e[0])return i(n(e[0]),e)}else if("object"==typeof e)return"string"==typeof e.data&&(e.data=JSON.parse(e.data)),e.data instanceof Array&&(e.fields||(e.fields=e.data[0]instanceof Array?e.fields:n(e.data[0])),e.data[0]instanceof Array||"object"==typeof e.data[0]||(e.data=[e.data])),i(e.fields||[],e.data||[]);throw"exception: Unable to serialize unrecognized input"}function n(e){function t(){if(E&&m&&(p("Delimiter","UndetectableDelimiter","Unable to auto-detect delimiting character; defaulted to '"+l.DefaultDelimiter+"'"),m=!1),e.skipEmptyLines)for(var t=0;t<E.data.length;t++)1==E.data[t].length&&""==E.data[t][0]&&E.data.splice(t--,1);return r()&&n(),a()}function r(){return e.header&&0==w.length}function n(){if(E){for(var e=0;r()&&e<E.data.length;e++)for(var t=0;t<E.data[e].length;t++)w.push(E.data[e][t]);E.data.splice(0,1)}}function a(){if(!E||!e.header&&!e.dynamicTyping)return E;for(var t=0;t<E.data.length;t++){for(var r={},n=0;n<E.data[t].length;n++){if(e.dynamicTyping){var i=E.data[t][n];"true"==i||"TRUE"===i?E.data[t][n]=!0:"false"==i||"FALSE"===i?E.data[t][n]=!1:E.data[t][n]=u(i)}e.header&&(n>=w.length?(r.__parsed_extra||(r.__parsed_extra=[]),r.__parsed_extra.push(E.data[t][n])):r[w[n]]=E.data[t][n])}e.header&&(E.data[t]=r,n>w.length?p("FieldMismatch","TooManyFields","Too many fields: expected "+w.length+" fields but parsed "+n,t):n<w.length&&p("FieldMismatch","TooFewFields","Too few fields: expected "+w.length+" fields but parsed "+n,t))}return e.header&&E.meta&&(E.meta.fields=w),E}function o(t){for(var r,n,a,s=[",","    ","|",";",l.RECORD_SEP,l.UNIT_SEP],f=0;f<s.length;f++){var o=s[f],d=0,u=0;a=void 0;for(var p=new i({delimiter:o,preview:10}).parse(t),c=0;c<p.data.length;c++){var h=p.data[c].length;u+=h,"undefined"!=typeof a?h>1&&(d+=Math.abs(h-a),a=h):a=h}u/=p.data.length,("undefined"==typeof n||n>d)&&u>1.99&&(n=d,r=o)}return e.delimiter=r,{successful:!!r,bestDelimiter:r}}function d(e){e=e.substr(0,1048576);var t=e.split("\r");if(1==t.length)return"\n";for(var r=0,n=0;n<t.length;n++)"\n"==t[n][0]&&r++;return r>=t.length/2?"\r\n":"\r"}function u(e){var t=g.test(e);return t?parseFloat(e):e}function p(e,t,r,n){E.errors.push({type:e,code:t,message:r,row:n})}var c,h,m,g=/^\s*-?(\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.?\d*)(e[-+]?\d+)?\s*$/i,y=this,v=0,b=!1,w=[],E={data:[],errors:[],meta:{}};if(f(e.step)){var x=e.step;e.step=function(n){if(E=n,r())t();else{if(t(),0==E.data.length)return;v+=n.data.length,e.preview&&v>e.preview?h.abort():x(E,y)}}}this.parse=function(r){if(e.newline||(e.newline=d(r)),m=!1,!e.delimiter){var n=o(r);n.successful?e.delimiter=n.bestDelimiter:(m=!0,e.delimiter=l.DefaultDelimiter),E.meta.delimiter=e.delimiter}var a=s(e);return e.preview&&e.header&&a.preview++,c=r,h=new i(a),E=h.parse(c),t(),!f(e.complete)||b||y.streamer&&!y.streamer.finished()||e.complete(E),b?{meta:{paused:!0}}:E||{meta:{paused:!1}}},this.pause=function(){b=!0,h.abort(),c=c.substr(h.getCharIndex())},this.resume=function(){b=!1,h=new i(e),h.parse(c),b||(y.streamer&&!y.streamer.finished()?y.streamer.resume():f(e.complete)&&e.complete(E))},this.abort=function(){h.abort(),f(e.complete)&&e.complete(E),c=""}}function i(e){e=e||{};var t=e.delimiter,r=e.newline,n=e.comments,i=e.step,a=e.preview,s=e.fastMode;if(("string"!=typeof t||1!=t.length||l.BAD_DELIMITERS.indexOf(t)>-1)&&(t=","),n===t)throw"Comment character same as delimiter";n===!0?n="#":("string"!=typeof n||l.BAD_DELIMITERS.indexOf(n)>-1)&&(n=!1),"\n"!=r&&"\r"!=r&&"\r\n"!=r&&(r="\n");var f=0,o=!1;this.parse=function(e){function l(){return w.push(e.substr(f)),v.push(w),f=c,y&&p(),u()}function d(t){v.push(w),w=[],f=t,O=e.indexOf(r,f)}function u(e){return{data:v,errors:b,meta:{delimiter:t,linebreak:r,aborted:o,truncated:!!e}}}function p(){i(u()),v=[],b=[]}if("string"!=typeof e)throw"Input must be a string";var c=e.length,h=t.length,m=r.length,g=n.length,y="function"==typeof i;f=0;var v=[],b=[],w=[];if(!e)return u();if(s){for(var E=e.split(r),x=0;x<E.length;x++)if(!n||E[x].substr(0,g)!=n){if(y){if(v=[E[x].split(t)],p(),o)return u()}else v.push(E[x].split(t));if(a&&x>=a)return v=v.slice(0,a),u(!0)}return u()}for(var D=e.indexOf(t,f),O=e.indexOf(r,f);;)if('"'!=e[f])if(n&&0===w.length&&e.substr(f,g)===n){if(-1==O)return u();f=O+m,O=e.indexOf(r,f),D=e.indexOf(t,f)}else if(-1!==D&&(O>D||-1===O))w.push(e.substring(f,D)),f=D+h,D=e.indexOf(t,f);else{if(-1===O)break;if(w.push(e.substring(f,O)),d(O+m),y&&(p(),o))return u();if(a&&v.length>=a)return u(!0)}else{var A=f;for(f++;;){var A=e.indexOf('"',A+1);if(-1===A)return b.push({type:"Quotes",code:"MissingQuotes",message:"Quoted field unterminated",row:v.length,index:f}),l();if(A===c-1)return w.push(e.substring(f,A).replace(/""/g,'"')),v.push(w),y&&p(),u();if('"'!=e[A+1]){if(e[A+1]==t){w.push(e.substring(f,A).replace(/""/g,'"')),f=A+1+h,D=e.indexOf(t,f),O=e.indexOf(r,f);break}if(e.substr(A+1,m)===r){if(w.push(e.substring(f,A).replace(/""/g,'"')),d(A+1+m),D=e.indexOf(t,f),y&&(p(),o))return u();if(a&&v.length>=a)return u(!0);break}}else A++}}return l()},this.abort=function(){o=!0},this.getCharIndex=function(){return f}}function a(e){"object"!=typeof e&&(e={});var t=s(e);return("string"!=typeof t.delimiter||1!=t.delimiter.length||l.BAD_DELIMITERS.indexOf(t.delimiter)>-1)&&(t.delimiter=o.delimiter),"\n"!=t.newline&&"\r"!=t.newline&&"\r\n"!=t.newline&&(t.newline=o.newline),"boolean"!=typeof t.header&&(t.header=o.header),"boolean"!=typeof t.dynamicTyping&&(t.dynamicTyping=o.dynamicTyping),"number"!=typeof t.preview&&(t.preview=o.preview),"function"!=typeof t.step&&(t.step=o.step),"function"!=typeof t.complete&&(t.complete=o.complete),"boolean"!=typeof t.skipEmptyLines&&(t.skipEmptyLines=o.skipEmptyLines),"boolean"!=typeof t.fastMode&&(t.fastMode=o.fastMode),t}function s(e){if("object"!=typeof e)return e;var t=e instanceof Array?[]:{};for(var r in e)t[r]=s(e[r]);return t}function f(e){return"function"==typeof e}var o={delimiter:"",newline:"",header:!1,dynamicTyping:!1,preview:0,step:void 0,comments:!1,complete:void 0,skipEmptyLines:!1,fastMode:!1},l={};return l.parse=t,l.parseFiles=e,l.unparse=r,l.RECORD_SEP=String.fromCharCode(30),l.UNIT_SEP=String.fromCharCode(31),l.BYTE_ORDER_MARK="\ufeff",l.BAD_DELIMITERS=["\r","\n",'"',l.BYTE_ORDER_MARK],l.DefaultDelimiter=",",l.Parser=i,l.ParserHandle=n,l}
```

Comment: Thanks I get a java.lang error when implementing this.  I would also like to understand why Papa Parse does not work . . .

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 4 "nlapiCreateForm('Add File', true" , you must close the parenthesis. Also, make sure your code works and you get the String before parsing it with Baby Parse. As to why Papa Parse doesnt work I believe its because Papa parse works on clientside, so I looked for a port that ran serverside. Baby Parse is a port of Papa Parse that runs on Node JS.